# How to edit label content from dll

Tags: c#, dll

I made a Windows Forms Application with Visual Studio. For some reason, I can not edit the content of a label with a .dll. In the .exe file, I **can** edit the text with `label1.Text="Something";`, but in the dll `label1.Text="Something";` doesn't work. I think tried using the namespace and class to change it, but that didn't work either. (I am not sure I tried this, but I think I did.) How am I supposed to change something in a Forms application with a .dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a reference to your Dll's class with the Form's instance which should be changed, but this is a bad practice.

It's better to use per example an event in your Dll class or call a function of your Dll from the Form and change the text there.

It's always better to separate UI from data classes.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: If you post your Dll class code (or at least the call who should change the label) and the call you are doing to it then yes :) Depending on what you must achieve then an approach is better than another one

Comment: I don't have my original code, because I figured a way to avoid that problem. Can you just give your own example code, or a link to some code that has something like this?